# PHP Curl UTF-8 Charset

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I have an php script which calls another web page and writes all the html of the page and everything goes ok however there is a charset problem. My php file encoding is utf-8 and all other php files work ok (that means there is no problem with server). What is the missing thing in that code and all spanish letters look weird. PS. When I wrote these weird characters original versions into php, they all look accurate.

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    $data=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
$html=file_get_contents_curl($_GET["u"]);
$doc=new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
```

Comment: "all spanish letters look weird" is not a cURL problem.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Simple:
When you use curl it encodes the string to `utf-8` you just need to decode them..

```
Description

string utf8_decode ( string $data )
```

This function decodes data , assumed to be `UTF-8` encoded, to `ISO-8859-1`.

Answer (score 16):

You Can use this header

```
   header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

and after decoding the string

```
 $page = utf8_decode(curl_exec($ch));
```

It worked for me

Answer (score 4):

```
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$result = iconv("Windows-1251", "UTF-8", $output);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function page_title($val){
    include(dirname(__FILE__).'/simple_html_dom.php');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$val);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $return = curl_exec($ch); 
    $encot = false;
    $charset = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);

    curl_close($ch); 
    $html = str_get_html('"'.$return.'"');

    if(strpos($charset,'charset=') !== false) {
        $c = str_replace("text/html; charset=","",$charset);
        $encot = true;
    }
    else {
        $lookat=$html->find('meta[http-equiv=Content-Type]',0);
        $chrst = $lookat->content;
        preg_match('/charset=(.+)/', $chrst, $found);
        $p = trim($found[1]);
        if(!empty($p) && $p != "")
        {
            $c = $p;
            $encot = true;
        }
    }
    $title = $html->find('title')[0]->innertext;
    if($encot == true && $c != 'utf-8' && $c != 'UTF-8') $title = mb_convert_encoding($title,'UTF-8',$c);

    return $title;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was fetching a windows-1252 encoded file via cURL and the `mb_detect_encoding(curl_exec($ch));` returned UTF-8. Tried `utf8_encode(curl_exec($ch));` and the characters were correct.

Comment: Thanks, i was having exactly the same problem, this answer should get more visibility.

Answer (score 3):

#### First method (internal function)

The best way I have tried before is to use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode). Keep in mind, don't use it for the whole url; instead, use it only for the needed parts. For example, a request that has two 'text-fa' and 'text-en' fields and they contain a Persian and an English text, respectively, you might only need to encode the Persian text, not the English one.

#### Second Method (using cURL function)

However, there are better ways if the range of characters have to be encoded is more limited. One of these ways is using `CURLOPT_ENCODING`, by passing it to [`curl_setopt()`](http://php.net/curl-setopt):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
```

Comment: ENCODING accepts the following: The contents of the "Accept-Encoding: " header. This enables decoding of the response. Supported encodings are "identity", "deflate", and "gzip". If an empty string, "", is set, a header containing all supported encoding types is sent.