# PHP Curl return character

Tags: php, curl

I'm doing a curl request and I'm getting this reply:-

Expected : "£12709"

Got : "Â£12709"

I have no clue what "Â" this character is.

Comment: Do you get that when sending a request outside of PHP?  I'm assuming youre not using utf-8.  Try `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"");`

Comment: Hi, im not sending request outside php. Just tried your solution and still no luck :(

Comment: This is probably UTF-8 data wrongly being interpreted as ISO-8859-1. You could use [`utf8_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) to decode it properly.

Comment: Two other SO questions on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761411/php-curl-utf-8-charset
and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649480/curl-import-character-encoding-problem

Comment: Maybe check the encoding and convert it like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649480/curl-import-character-encoding-problem

Comment: Hi, Thanks that link helped me, all I did was included header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); on the top of my php and now I dont get the extra character.

Comment: @JohnMcMahon if you put that  comment as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found these two similar SO posts that may be helpful:

[PHP Curl UTF-8 Charset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761411/php-curl-utf-8-charset)

[CURL import character encoding problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649480/curl-import-character-encoding-problem)