# Unicode is getting Encoded CURL PHP

Tags: php, web-scraping, unicode, php-curl

```
    if ($_GET["link"]!=""){
$curl = curl_init('http://exaple.com'.$link);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

$page = curl_exec($curl);
echo $page;
}
```

Hi, the website is in other language. the characters are getting encoded. i am getting "??" and strange texts instead of character "á" "i" "á" etc (Unicode).
Is there any way to make it work ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761411/php-curl-utf-8-charset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First** you have to identify the source website character encoding.

Choose a page and download it... using the terminal, type:

```
$ curl -D headers.txt -o page.html http:/www.example.com/index.html
```

The response headers are saved into `headers.txt` while the page source html is stored into `page.html`

Inspect the two files with a text editor and search for `Content-Type` you should find indication of the character encoding at least in one of them.

If you're not successfull you can use `file` to try to "guess" the character encoding by inspecting the file contents:

```
$ file -I page.html
```

The output looks like this:

```
page.html: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
```

---

**Second** you have to decide or understand what the **destination** character set is:

- are you storing the web page into a text file? What is the expected character encoding of the file?
- are you parsing the web page within PHP in order to fetch some data of your interest?
- are you serving back the webpage (totally or partially) on your website? What is the character encoding of the website?

Let's assume (for example) you want to end up with Unicode characters encoded as **UTF-8**.

---

**Finally** improve your PHP script to make the proper charset conversion after the page is retrieved with `$page = curl_exec($curl);`

You may use [**`mb-convert_encoding`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

```
$page = mb_convert_encoding( $page, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8' );
//                      from ----------^            ^--------to
```

Alternatively [**`iconv`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) can be used for the same purpose.